# Trouble downloading PhantomJS generated pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stream, phantomjs

I am having some trouble downloading a PhantomJS generated file to my asp.net application. 
I am running phantomJs as a server:
The file is generated correctly and saved to disk in the PhantomJS folder, but something happens during the transfer and inclusion into my Http response stream. The file is downloaded by the browser, but when I try to open it, the file errors with the message that it can't be opened. I suspect it gets corrupted in the stream transfer?

I would like to avoid reading the pdf from its stored location in the file system, and instead get it out of the response returned from PhantomJS

PhantomJS code:

```
page.open(url, function (status) {

    page.render(fullFileName);

    var fs = require('fs');

    var pdfContent = fs.read(fullFileName);
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.headers = {
                    'Cache': 'no-cache',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
                    'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
                    'Content-Length': pdfContent.length
                    };

     response.setEncoding("binary");
     response.write(pdfContent);


});
```

ASP.NET code:

```
public ActionResult DownloadPdfFromUrl(ConvertionModel model)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080");

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = string.Format("url={0}&fileName=myTest&extension=pdf&format=pdf", model.UrlToConvertPdf);
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        httpWReq.Method = "POST";
        httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (Stream s = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            s.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");

        return new FileStreamResult(response.GetResponseStream(), "application/pdf");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# code looks good, but it's better not to return null action result. I'd better write

```
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

var buffer = new byte[response.ContentLength];
stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

return File(buffer, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
```

Also set response encoding in PhantomJS before writing document body:

```
response.setEncoding("binary");
response.write(pdfContent);
```

Comment: Yeah I updated it to return a FileStreamResult to avoid the buffer parsing/null return value

Comment: I was experiementing with the binary option (updated question). With that setting I'm able to open the downloaded pdf, but it opens as a blank pdf with just a white background

Comment: And does the downloaded pdf have the same size and content as one produced on server?

Comment: No they differ The one on the server is bigger by 2 Kb. I am assuming it's an encoding issue that causes it to be corrupted

Comment: And is Content-Length returned by PhantomJS equal to the server-side file size? Probably `fs.read(filename)` reads it as text, so you need `fs.open(filename, 'rb').read()` to read it as binary stream.

Comment: Ah. You're totally correct. fs.open(filename, 'rb').read() did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: For production use you'd better rewrite it as `var pdfStream = fs.open(filename, 'rb'); var pdfContent = pdfStream.read(); pdfStream.close();`.